# Use camera to control applications on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, camera, gestures, alt-tab

Is there a way I can use the camera on my Macbook Pro to control the applications on my desktop? I would like to be able to wave to use waving gestures to change between apps, show the app expose, etc.

Do you know of any applications that can do this? I haven't been able to find one and I've done extensive Google searching.

Comment: It would almost certainly require a jailbreak, because App Store apps aren't allowed to modify system behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an app called [Flutter](https://flutterapp.com/) but Google bought them and there is no official download link there currently, although there is one on [download.com](http://download.cnet.com/Flutter/3000-31711_4-75804659.html).

Note: Reading through the site, it seems it only works with music tracks. Bummer.

Comment: Flutter is pretty good!